# Binding to a datagrid, database alterations triggering on client side

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, data-binding

I am writing an application that is basically a DataGrid attached to a database table, nice and simple. I am using LINQ to SQL and binding to the table via a simple:

`dGridd.ItemsSource = _dbcontext.TheTableObjects;`

The table successfully shows the table, however the DataGrid does not get updated when I alter the database values externally ( e.g. from MSSQL ). I have followed most instructions here:[Simple Demo of Binding to a Database in WPF using LINQ-SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/binding_in_linq-sql.aspx) , with the exception of skipping the use of the ObservableCollection ( which should be no difference, correct? ).

I want the binding to update ( and therefore the datagrid ) when the content of the database table changes externally. Instinctively I said to myself: 'this is stupid... how can the client application possibly know the database contents without some sort of polling?...' but then again I dont know just how wizzy LINQ to SQL really is...

Comment: your instincts were correct.  you must poll. use an ObservableCollection to Add, Remove delta instances which will automatically propagate to the DataGrid.

Comment: Does the app do anything else besides display values?  If need to have other buttons/features hot then you will need to perform the polling in the background.  If it is read only you might want to go with ListView / GridView as it is lighter than DataGrid.  You might be able to use a CLR trigger to get notification  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131093.aspx .  I said might - I did not post this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry ask another question in the question, but: What is the least UI interfearing way of polling a DB and filling a grid? At the moment I'm simply updating the `ObservableQueue` in a `DispatcherTimer`, every time this fires I feel the UI lag slightly. Is there a better way of doing this as far as application responsiveness goes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jberger provided the best answer.

> your instincts were correct. you must poll. use an ObservableCollection to Add, Remove delta instances which will automatically propagate to the DataGrid"